# Could not load file or assembly CefSharp.Core.Runtime

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, cefsharp

Когда я пытаюсь использовать тип `CefSharp.BrowserSettings`, получаю следующее исключение:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
> 'CefSharp.Core.Runtime, Version=105.3.330.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138'. Не удается найти указанный файл.'

При этом остальные компоненты работают нормально (например `ChromiumWebBrowser`).

- Целевая платформа: .NET Core 6.0
- Пакет: CefSharp.Offscreen.NETCore 105.3.330

Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable установлен.

Comment: `Не удается найти указанный файл`

Comment: Да, я вижу. Но файл CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll лежит вместе с CefSharp.Core.dll

Comment: Его версия и PublicKeyToken совпадает?

Comment: @aepot Да, совпадает

Comment: а в папке с билдом она есть?

Comment: @aepot Вы имеет ввиду в папке с готовой сборкой? Только там и есть (папка runtimes).

Comment: Ради эксперимента скопируйте в папку к экзешнику

Comment: @aepot Ошибка остаётся

Comment: Оно? https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/4245